# Thread Error in Xcode w/ Swift When Launching New Screen

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

Once the user logs into my app, I set the window, set the rootViewController and makeKeyAndVisible and when I do I get a `Thread 9: signal SIGABRT` error. FWIW, I get a purple warning `-[UIWindow initWithFrame:] must be used from main thread only` when setting `self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`. See code below to see my setup.

The code dies with that error right here - `self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()` in the `launchWindow(aWindow: UIWindow?)` function below in AppController.swift.

*AppDelegate.swift*

```swift
//
//  AppDelegate.swift


import UIKit
import AWSCognitoAuth
import AWSSNS
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider
import UserNotifications
import ESTabBarController_swift
import AWSMobileClient

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard?
    var loginViewController: LoginViewController?
    var pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.init(forKey: "UserPool")

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        AppController.sharedInstance.enableCognitoClientWithAuthentication()

        // setup logging
//        pool.delegate = self
//        AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose
//        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1,
//                                                                identityPoolId: Constants.APIKeys.AWSIdentityPoolID)
//
//        // setup service configuration
//        let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
//
//        // create pool configuration
//        let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: Constants.APIKeys.AWSClientID,
//                                                                        clientSecret: Constants.APIKeys.AWSSecret,
//                                                                        poolId: Constants.APIKeys.AWSPoolID)
//        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration
//        // initialize user pool client
//        AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: "UserPool")
//
//        pool.currentUser()?.getSession()
        // fetch the user pool client we initialized in above step
        //let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")

        let signedIn = AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().isSignedIn
        self.navigationController = UINavigationController()
        if !signedIn {
            navigationInit()
        }
//        } else {
//            AppController.sharedInstance.showLoggedInStateAndReturn(true)
//        }

                //pool.delegate = self
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        AppController.sharedInstance.launchInWindow(aWindow: self.window)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        navigationInit()

        return true
    }

    func navigationInit() {

        let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: false)


    }

    //MARK: Push Notification

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        /// Attach the device token to the user defaults
        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }

        print(token)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "deviceTokenForSNS")

        /// Create a platform endpoint. In this case, the endpoint is a
        /// device endpoint ARN
        let sns = AWSSNS.default()
        let request = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
        request?.token = token
        request?.platformApplicationArn = Constants.APIKeys.AWSSSNSARN

        sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject? in
            if task.error != nil {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: task.error))")
            } else {
                let createEndpointResponse = task.result! as AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
                if let endpointArnForSNS = createEndpointResponse.endpointArn {
                    print("endpointArn: \(endpointArnForSNS)")
                    Settings.setPushArn(endpointArnForSNS)

                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "RegisteredForPush"), object: nil)

                }
            }

            return nil
        })
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let visible = window?.visibleViewController()

        if let data = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
            if let route = data["route"] as? String {
                switch route {
                case "matchRequested":
                    var projectId = ""
                    if let project = data["projectId"] as? String {
                        projectId = project
                    }
                    var matchId = ""
                    if let match = data["matchId"] as? String {
                        matchId = match
                    }
                    let projectMatches = MatchRequestedViewController(withNotificationPayload: projectId, matchId: matchId)
                    visible?.navigationController?.pushViewController(projectMatches, animated: true)

                case "projectDetails":
                    var projectId = ""
                    if let project = data["projectId"] as? String {
                        projectId = project
                    }
                    let projectMatches = ProjectDetailsViewController(withProject: TERMyProject(), orProjectId: projectId)
                    visible?.navigationController?.pushViewController(projectMatches, animated: true)
                case "matched":
                    var projectId = ""
                    if let project = data["projectId"] as? String {
                        projectId = project
                    }
                    var matchId = ""
                    if let match = data["matchId"] as? String {
                        matchId = match
                    }
                    var originProject: TERMyProject = TERMyProject()
                    var matchedProject: TERMatchedProject = TERMatchedProject()

                    AppController.sharedInstance.AWSClient?.projectsGet(id:projectId).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in

                        if let error = task.error {
                            print("Error: \(error)")

                        } else if let result = task.result {
                            if result is NSDictionary {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    let array = [result]
                                    let parsedProject: [TERMyProject] = TERMyProject.parseFromAPI(array:array as! [NSDictionary])
                                    for project in parsedProject {
                                        originProject = project
                                    }
                                    //                        self.initialSetup()
                                }
                                AppController.sharedInstance.AWSClient?.projectsGet(id:matchId).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in

                                    if let error = task.error {
                                        print("Error: \(error)")

                                    } else if let result = task.result {
                                        if result is NSDictionary {
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                let array = [result]
                                                let parsedProject: [TERMatchedProject] = TERMatchedProject.parseFromAPI(array:array as! [NSDictionary])
                                                for project in parsedProject {
                                                    matchedProject = project
                                                }
                                                let projectMatches = MatchedViewController(withProject: originProject, match: matchedProject, isComplete: false)
                                                visible?.navigationController?.pushViewController(projectMatches, animated: true)
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    return nil
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        return nil
                    })



                default:
                    break
                }

            }
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    //MARK: Boiler-plate methods

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

}


extension AppDelegate: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate {

//    func startPasswordAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {
//        if (self.navigationController == nil) {
//
//            self.navigationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? UINavigationController
//        }
//
//        if (self.loginViewController == nil) {
//            self.loginViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? LoginViewController
//        }
//
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//            self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
//            if (!self.navigationController!.isViewLoaded
//                || self.navigationController!.view.window == nil) {
//                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(self.navigationController!,
//                                                         animated: true,
//                                                         completion: nil)
//            }
//
//        }
//        return self.loginViewController!
//    }


}

// MARK:- AWSCognitoIdentityRememberDevice protocol delegate

extension AppDelegate: AWSCognitoIdentityRememberDevice {
    func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {

    }


    func getRememberDevice(_ rememberDeviceCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSNumber>) {


    }

}
extension UIWindow {

    func visibleViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let rootViewController: UIViewController = self.rootViewController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: rootViewController)
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc:UIViewController) -> UIViewController {

        switch(vc){
        case is UINavigationController:
            let navigationController = vc as! UINavigationController
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom( vc: navigationController.visibleViewController!)
            break;

        case is UITabBarController:
            let tabBarController = vc as! UITabBarController
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: tabBarController.selectedViewController!)
            break;

        default:
            if let presentedViewController = vc.presentedViewController {
                //print(presentedViewController)
                if let presentedViewController2 = presentedViewController.presentedViewController {
                    return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: presentedViewController2)
                }
                else{
                    return vc;
                }
            }
            else{
                return vc;
            }
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

*AppController.swift*

```
    func launchInWindow(aWindow: UIWindow?){

        self.window = aWindow

        self.initializeSDKs()
        self.globalCustomization()

        self.AWSUnAuthedClient.apiKey = Constants.APIKeys.AWSAPIKey


        self.window!.rootViewController = self.showLoggedInStateAndReturn(true)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

    func initializeSDKs() {

        // Google places
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(Constants.APIKeys.GooglePlaces)
    }

    func globalCustomization() {
        self.styleNavigationBar()
    }

    @discardableResult func showLoggedInStateAndReturn(_ shouldReturn: Bool) -> UIViewController? {

        //AppController.sharedInstance.enableCognitoClientWithAuthentication()
        //self.registerForPush()

        self.tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
        //tabBarController.delegate = delegate
        self.tabBarController?.title = "Irregularity"
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage.image(with: UIColor("FFFFFF", alpha: 0.0)!)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.image(with: UIColor("2A2A27")!)
        self.tabBarController?.shouldHijackHandler = {
            tabbarController, viewController, index in
            if index == 1 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

            self.tabBarController?.didHijackHandler = {
            [weak tabBarController] tabbarController, viewController, index in

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                let newProjectNavCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NewProjectViewController())
                newProjectNavCon.hero.isEnabled = true
                newProjectNavCon.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
                newProjectNavCon.hero.navigationAnimationType = .fade
                tabBarController?.present(newProjectNavCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        let centerVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())

        let v1 = centerVC
        let v2 = BaseViewController()
        let v3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ProfileViewController())

        v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarBouncesContentView(), title: "Projects", image: UIImage(named: "tabBar"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabBar"))
        v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarIrregularityContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "tabBarPlusButton"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabBarPlusButton"))
        v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarBouncesContentView(), title: "Profile", image: UIImage(named: "tabBarProfile"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabBarProfile"))

        self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers([v1, v2, v3], animated: true)

        if shouldReturn {
            return self.tabBarController
        } else {
            self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabBarController
            return nil
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your code for AppDelegate.swift is the one you are using? Looks like "self.window = ..." lives outside of a function and shouldn't. Can you update your question with the right codebase?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to execute the piece of code in the `main thread`:

```
func launchInWindow(aWindow: UIWindow?){
    self.window = aWindow
    self.initializeSDKs()
    self.globalCustomization()
    self.AWSUnAuthedClient.apiKey = Constants.APIKeys.AWSAPIKey

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.window!.rootViewController = self.showLoggedInStateAndReturn(true)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Also, your question codebase looks a little bit weird in this part in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) //-- Purple warning here
AppController.sharedInstance.launchInWindow(aWindow: self.window)

return true
```

Looks like those three lines are not in a function but in class scope, which is weird and you shouldn't be able to compile it. Probably you pasted your code wrong?

Comment: After updating that method to match what you put above, that resolved it but now, after log in is complete and the home screen loads. I tap the menu button on the upper left and get this error now. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <HomeViewController: 0x7f8d6e837380>.'`

Comment: @user11263671 I just read your message now sorry. Looking at your codebase and the last error you got, it looks like you are trying to present a viewcontroller which is already active in UITabBarController, that's why app crashes. But that's another question and to not push that through comments I suggest you to put it as a new question, meanwhile if the issue you had in the original question is solved, please mark an answer correct/accepted to let others know.